# Java Applet+Html Script_Concerns with String Default HOST "127.0.0.1"

Tags: javascript, java, applet

We use java appelt in webbased directory, published using html file (contains javascript functions which is used to communicate with the embedded java applet).

It is used for simple caller identification CTI function, where applet focuses on loopback ip 127.0.0.1 and some tcp port. Solution works great with local PC (accessing directory using native browser), however we have a situation when its comes to directory access over terminal server/Citrix/Thinapps.

Could you please provide me with some insights on how to extend this applet to get it work on Citrix/Thinapps ? Is there a way to use a 'function' to replace variable '127.0.0.1'? {applet was not built by me and I'd consider myself a beginner - Hope you guys can help me}

```
Private Static Final String DEFAULT HOST = "127.0.0.1"
Private Static Final String DEFAULT PORT = "xxxxx"
Script
<param name="host" value="127.0.0.1" /><param name="port" value="xxxxx"
```

Comment: does the program always make use of `DEFAULT_HOST`/`_PORT` or is there a way to set/override it on the command line? What would be the value you have to use actually, can you get a tunnel or so thru the terminal server/Citrix??

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks for your response. This applet employs DEFAULT HOST/PORT all the time, in the local client (non-citrix) we have simple C# commandline listning on corresponding port. This is within WAN.

Comment: Hi, We managed to figure it out - Thanks for your inputs!